# Using PHP functions in .env (dotenv) file

Tags: php, laravel, phpdotenv

I'm trying to use a PHP function in .env file which is `rand()` in my case.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve in .env;

```
PROTOCOL="http"
DOMAIN="example.com"
URI="www.{$DOMAIN}"
RAND=rand(1,5)
CDN_URI="cdn{$RAND}.{$DOMAIN}"
CDN_URL="{$PROTOCOL}://{$CDN_URI}"
```

As you can see, I am trying to generate random integers from 1 to 5 which represent the CDN subdomain so that in a request I would get `http://cdn2.example.com` and in another one `http://cdn4.example.com` and so on.

I guess using PHP in .env is not natively supported but is there any way / workaround ?

P.S. I am using Laravel 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.env` file, as plain text, doesn't have support to PHP functions. This file was designed as a fallback for your environment variables (from the OS), so you cannot use PHP code on that. You can use a global variable to do something similar if you really need a global random number, instead:

```
global $rand;
$rand = rand(1,5);
```

Then where you need to use your number outside the main context (like inside functions), you'll need to declare `global $rand`:

```
function someFunction ()
{
    global $rand;
    doSomethingWithRand($rand);
}
```

But it's an ugly approach in my opinion. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, there is a better way to do that.

### Update

Since you're using Laravel. You can add the call to `rand()` function in some of your config files, under `/config/` dir, like: `'rand' => rand(1,5),`. Then to access your random number, you should use:

```
// If your config was set inside /config/app.php.
config('app.rand');

// OR

// If your config was set inside /config/services.php, for instance.
config('services.rand');
```

Reference: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation#accessing-configuration-values

Comment: That's the only working solution atm.  Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: This is a well written answer. I don't know if it works, but have my upvote nonetheless, sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP in your environment file by using a well syntax like that :

```
<?php
return array(
    'PROTOCOL' => "http",
    'DOMAIN' => "example.com",
    'URI' => "www.{$DOMAIN}",
    'RAND' => rand(1,5),
    'CDN_URI' => "cdn{$RAND}.{$DOMAIN}",
    'CDN_URL' => "{$PROTOCOL}://{$CDN_URI}",
);
```

Comment: You'll get a parse error when trying to run this code. Your array is missing `>` to associate values to keys, like this: `'PROTOCOL' => "http",`.

Comment: Thanks ! Begginer's mistake !

Comment: Well, it did not work.  I got error 500.  I guess PHP code won't work in .env as @GustavoStraube mentioned.

Comment: I actually use an .env similar with Laravel 4. It works.

Comment: Oh then I guess in Laravel 5, things have changed.